# Password shared in post

Tags: support

I recently came across a stack overflow question where the OP publicly shared his real username and password for an e-commerce site. I immediately commented on the post to alert him and flagged it for moderator intervention. Another user edited the post to remove the information, however it is still accessible in the edit history.

What should I do in this situation?

Comment: You've already did everything necessary/possible.

Comment: See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132117/what-should-i-do-if-a-user-posts-sensitive-information-as-part-of-a-question-or

Comment: Every edited posts have their history attached on it; all sensitive contents are OP's full responsibility when posting (it can't preventing someone accessing post history & use their credentials unless the post is deleted by OP).

Comment: Most importantly:  don't panic.  This happens more often than you realize (and that's scary enough).  Flagging moderators is *more* than plenty; we mere mortals aren't going to be of any use to you.

Comment: The moderator flag you raised about it worked. It just took a while, because we get a *lot* of flags. A moderator got to it about 2 hours after you raised the flag, and then another moderator approved the first moderator's redaction about 2 hours after that. Overall, 4 hours is a pretty speedy flag-handling time-table. Unfortunately, it's too slow to prevent malicious actors from abusing the shared credentials. Which is a good reason why you should scrutinize your *own* posts, without relying on moderators to clean up after you. There's only so much we can do, and only so quickly.